# mysql_real_query vs mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

What is the difference between `mysql_real_query` and `mysql_query`? I've made a quick google search but could not find any link that shows the difference between the two.

Comment: Does mysql_real_query even exist?

Comment: @Jon: don't know for PHP, but it exists in libmysqlclient.

Comment: mysql_real_query exists only using the connector API

Comment: For your second question (which btw you shouldn't do on SO), you should look into prepared statements. Preferrably using PDO, as the older mysql_ functions do not allow for that.

Comment: @Shaokan If your question is so trivial it's only one sentence, it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If your question is too short to be asked, add more information.  Adding a second, wholly unrelated question in the text of your first question makes everything confusing.  Remove your second question from this text and do a little bit of googling, I *promise* that second question has been asked before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

mysql_real_query() doesn't exist in PHP. However, mysqli_real_query() exists.

According to the official MySQL manual (the C API): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-query.html

> mysql_query() cannot be used for statements that contain binary data; you must use mysql_real_query() instead. (Binary data may contain the “\0” character, which mysql_query() interprets as the end of the statement string.) In addition, mysql_real_query() is faster than mysql_query() because it does not call strlen() on the statement string.

About your second issue, the best way to insert multiple records is to create an INSERT query with multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 1), (2,2), (3,3)
```

And so on.
This will insert all the new rows in 1 operation, so it should be faster than running 3 queries, one per each row.

PS: You should consider using an extension that supports prepared statements, like MySQLi (note the i) or, even better, PDO.
Not only prepared statements are safer (if you use them correctly, they're 100% safe against SQL injections), but also let you do things like those you see in the examples in this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php (you can do that with INSERT queries as well, of course). Ah, and PDO is also object-oriented, which is nice :)

Comment: I edited it, suggesting the use of prepared statements, which can be used to insert many rows and are really efficient (if you enclose all queries into a transaction, it's even faster). And PDO is better for many other things.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is solely in the C API. One takes a C-style string, the other a buffer and length attribute to allow for NUL bytes. PHP internally uses `mysql_real_query`.

Comment: Shouldn't your last sentence be "PHP internally uses libmysql's C version of`mysql_real_query`"?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official PHP function mysql_real_query

http://php.net/mysql_real_query

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(3,4,5)
```

This will add three new rows in table1 which should have the columns a, b and c (and possibly others which have default values or can be null).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why I was rated down? In the original posting there were two questions the second of which I answered.